# indigo source installation problems:

Tags: ros, rviz, rosdep, hector-quadrotor, build-from-source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i first had installed ros indigo using apt,then after uninstalling i installed ros from source,now i am facing so many problems..

- whenever i use rosdep for installing dependencies it gets installed to my /opt/ros/indigo location and when i catkin_makes them it shows messages showing the required dependency packages were not found
- when i tried to roslaunch a demo([hector_quadrotor outdoor flight demo](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_quadrotor/Tutorials/Quadrotor%20outdoor%20flight%20demo)) my rviz shows error and exits **Which earlier used to work fine**

**can anybody help me?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224090/indigo-source-installation-problems:../) by [Azharudeen](https://answers.ros.org/users/23697/azharudeen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2016-01-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2016-01-15**:
Please specify exactly what you are doing, what you want to achieve and what happens instead, including the exact commands and outputs verbatim. The second bullet seems like a different issue that should be in a separate question.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2016-01-15**:
catkin_make for packages installed via rosdep install is not necessary and usually also not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have an another way around for installing dependencies using rosinstall_generator

- **[rosinstall_generator <pkg_name> --deps --exclude RPP  >  <pkg_name>.rosinstall]**{this will create a rosinstall file with all uninstlled dependencies listed}
- **[rosinstall src/ <pkg_name>.rosinstall]**{this will install the packages mentioned in the rosinstall file}

**nb:** Do this in the catkin root directory

---

Originally posted by [Azharudeen](https://answers.ros.org/users/23697/azharudeen/) with karma: 90 on 2016-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0